# node.js integration (using npm package kerberos) with kerberized Hadoop cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, hadoop, npm, kerberos

We have a Kerberos enabled Hadoop hortonworks cluster, I have installed node.js on one of the data nodes.I have to make node.js kerberized, to start with I have installed npm package kerberos on the node.js.

What are the other steps I need to follow, in order to connect node.js with kerberized Hadoop tools such as Kafka, Hive etc. If anyone have some sample examples around this, please share Or if you have any other options please share that too.

Comment: This isn't really a development question, but google will help you on this.. There is no specific problem here.. Are you running into any problems itself ? This related ? : http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/14/a-secure-hdfs-client-example/

Comment: @Pogrindis , Well for me it seems to be a valid question, I want to make node.js kerberized by leveraging hadoop kerberos infrastructure as first step and then integrate with kerberized hadoop tools. The example you have shared is clean kerberos hdfs connection within hadoop not from node.js.